# dagster solid Parallel Run Test exmaple

Tags: dagster

I tried to run parallel, but it didn't work as I expected

The progress bar doesn't work the way I thought it would.

I think that both operations should be executed at the same time.

but first run find_highest_calorie_cereal after find_highest_protein_cereal

[image: 1]

```
import csv
import time
import requests
from dagster import pipeline, solid


# start_complex_pipeline_marker_0
@solid
def download_cereals():
    response = requests.get("https://docs.dagster.io/assets/cereal.csv")
    lines = response.text.split("\n")
    return [row for row in csv.DictReader(lines)]


@solid
def find_highest_calorie_cereal(cereals):
    time.sleep(5)
    sorted_cereals = list(
        sorted(cereals, key=lambda cereal: cereal["calories"])
    )
    return sorted_cereals[-1]["name"]


@solid
def find_highest_protein_cereal(context, cereals):
    time.sleep(10)
    sorted_cereals = list(
        sorted(cereals, key=lambda cereal: cereal["protein"])
    )
    # for i in range(1, 11):
    #     context.log.info(str(i) + '~~~~~~~~')
    #     time.sleep(1)

    return sorted_cereals[-1]["name"]


@solid
def display_results(context, most_calories, most_protein):
    context.log.info(f"Most caloric cereal 테스트: {most_calories}")
    context.log.info(f"Most protein-rich cereal: {most_protein}")


@pipeline
def complex_pipeline():
    cereals = download_cereals()
    display_results(
        most_protein=find_highest_protein_cereal(cereals),
        most_calories=find_highest_calorie_cereal(cereals),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you should set up a executor with parallelism available. You could use multiprocess_executor.

> "Executors are responsible for executing steps within a pipeline run.
> Once a run has launched and the process for the run, or run worker,
> has been allocated and started, the executor assumes responsibility
> for execution."

1. modes provide the possible set of executors one can use. Use the executor_defs property on ModeDefinition.

`MODE_DEV = ModeDefinition(name="dev", executor_defs=[multiprocess_executor])`

`@pipeline(mode_defs=[MODE_DEV], preset_defs=[Preset_test])`

2. the execution config section of the run config determines the actual executor.

in the yml file or run_config, set:

```
execution:
  multiprocess:
    config:
      max_concurrent: 4
```

retrieved from : https://docs.dagster.io/deployment/executors

Comment: See https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/solids-pipelines/pipeline-execution#multiprocessing-execution